# Lagrange dual function of standard form LP

Tags: proof-explanation, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Consider the linear program to minimize $c^Tx$ subject to $Ax=b,x\succeq0.$

Boyd gave us its lagrange and dual function in his book as followings,

$L(x, \lambda, \nu)=c^Tx-\lambda ^Tx+\nu ^T(Ax-b)=-b^T\nu+(c+A^T\nu-\lambda)^Tx$

and

$g(\lambda, \nu)=\inf L(x, \lambda, \nu), x\in D=-b^T\nu$ only when $A^T\nu-\lambda+c=0$, and $-\infty$ otherwise.

By definition, $D$ is the domain of the primal problem and the primal problem requires $x \succeq 0$. So why we can't say

$g(\lambda, \nu)=-b^T\nu$ only when $A^T\nu-\lambda+c \succeq 0$,

since infimum of $(A^T\nu-\lambda+c)^Tx$ is $0$ for $A^T\nu-\lambda+c \succeq 0$ and $x \succeq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you minimize the Lagrangian the inequality constraint
$$x\geq 0$$
Has been baked in to the Lagrangian expression. When we optimize the Lagrangian expression $x$ is unconstrained. I.e. $D$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$.